# How do I animate my R Shiny plot's output based on the increments of slider input value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, slider, shiny-reactivity

I've looked through R Shiny tutorials and stackoverflow for answers related to my query. I usually wait for 3-4 days to solve a coding problem before I attempt to post.

I have an animated slider in my UI that loops through time interval in a column (column a) . I'm trying to produce an animated line plot that plots y values of another column (column b),  corresponding to the nrow() of that time interval. The slider works perfectly, but I haven't been able to plot the output.

I mightve missed some concepts related to reactivity in Shiny app. Appreciate any guidance I can get related to my query. I'll be happy to post more info if needed.

```
a <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)    
b <- c(50,100,40,30,20,80)    

mydata <- cbind(a,b)    
mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata())

ui <- fluidPage (

  headerPanel("basic app"),

  sidebarPanel(

    sliderInput("slider",
                label = "Time elapsed",
                min = 0,
                max = nrow(mydata()),
                value = 1, step = 1,
                animate =
                  animationOptions(interval = 200, loop = TRUE))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Name = "slider",
      Value = input$slider)
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    x<- as.numeric(input$slider)
    y <- as.numeric(b[x])
    ggplot(mydata,aes_string(x,y))+ geom_line()
  })
}
```

Just as a demo, I wanted the animated plot to come out like this, but in correspondance to UI slider values :

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)
fake <- c(1,10)
goods <- c(11,20)
fakegoods <- cbind(fake,goods)
fakegoods <- data.frame(fakegoods)
ggplot(fakegoods, aes(fake, goods)) + geom_line() + transition_reveal(1, fake)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this accomplish what you are looking for? Note that I removed the first element, `0`, from vector `a` as your original example had more elements in `a` than `b`, and in order for them to be `cbind` together they must be the same length.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)    
b <- c(50,100,40,30,20,80)    

mydata <- cbind(a,b)    
mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata)

ui <- fluidPage (

  headerPanel("basic app"),

  sidebarPanel(

    sliderInput("slider",
                label = "Time elapsed",
                min = min(mydata$a),
                max = max(mydata$a),
                value = min(mydata$a), step = 1,
                animate =
                  animationOptions(interval = 200, loop = TRUE))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plotdata <- mydata[1:which(input$slider==mydata$a),]
    p <- ggplot(plotdata,aes(x = a,y = b))

    if(nrow(plotdata)==1) {
      p + geom_point()
    } else {
      p + geom_line()
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried it and I got "Warning: Error in :: argument of length 0", which means I'll have to get rid of the NA values first?

Comment: where do you have `NA` values? There were no `NA` values mentioned in your OP. Please make sure your question is complete and contains all information.

Comment: Apologies for that, I'll make my info more complete next time ! Thank you for the input, my code finally works now !

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works. If my answer helped, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).